# Why does ICU4J return the byte-order-mark when reading an array of bytes into a String?

Tags: java, encoding, icu

I read a file into an array of bytes. Then I use ICU4J to detect the file's encoding (I don't know what the encoding might be, these files can have multiple different encodings) and return a Unicode String.
Like so:

```
byte[] fileContent = // read file into byte array
CharsetDetector cd = new CharsetDetector();
cd.setText(fileContent);
CharsetMatch cm = cd.detect();
String result = cm.getString();
```

When my file is encoded using UTF-16LE the first character in "result" is the byte-order-mark. I'm not interested in this and because it is specific to the encoding scheme and not really part of the file content I would expect it to be gone.

Yet ICU4J returns it. Why is this happening and is there some way of getting around this problem? The only solution I see is manually checking if the first character in the returned String is the byte order mark and stripping it manually. Is there some cleaner/better way?

Comment: A class called `CharsetMatch` returned by `CharsetDetector.detect()` - I don't know but somehow I'd expect it to hold the detected Charset ... without knowing ICU4J ...

Comment: @Fildor It does hold the detected Charset. What I'm asking is why the result of cm.getString() contains a BOM (which to me seems to be part of the encoding convention rather than file content)

Comment: I just consulted the docs ... http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/CharsetMatch.html#getString(). They in fact say that it returns the corresponding Java String but they do not say anything about removing the BOM. So I'd expect it to be there if it was in the first place.

Comment: @Fildor Good point. Actually the standard Java new String(fileContent, "UTF-16LE") also gives a String containing the BOM. Soo... are you saying that for you it's natural that BOM is also retrieved? For me it would be natural for the BOM to be gone because it's encoding specific.

Comment: Yes, to me it is natural that it is also retrieved. I'd expect them to explicitly mention it in the docs if they were trimming out the BOM.

Comment: Ok, thanks, this helped me have a look at the issue from a different point of view. I think the answer is here http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom1 - "Under some higher level protocols, use of a BOM may be mandatory (or prohibited) in the Unicode data stream defined in that protocol.". If you add this as an answer I will accept it because our discussion helped me out. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just consulted the docs ... icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/…. They in fact say that it returns the corresponding Java String but they do not say anything about removing the BOM. So I'd expect it to be there if it was in the first place.

To me it is natural that it is also retrieved. I'd expect them to explicitly mention it in the docs if they were trimming out the BOM.

> I think the answer is here unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom1 - "Under some higher level protocols, use of a BOM may be mandatory (or prohibited) in the Unicode data stream defined in that protocol."

I think that's pretty much it. If a BOM is mandatory, you'd have to add it again. Filtering it out if the BOM is prohibited is considered the easy part I guess :)